# Proper use of the rootProperty in Sencha Touch 2

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2, foursquare

I am trying to use the rootProperty value in a Sencha Touch 2 store to load some JSON I retrieved from the Foursquare Venues API and for the life of me I cannot get it to work.

According to the docs I should setup my rootProperty in dot notation to equal "response.venues" but it does not populate the list. I put the json in a separate file and removed the "response" and "venues" headers and it worked fine. There must be something blatantly obvious I'm missing here as I can't find a straight answer anywhere.

My model:

```
Ext.define('App.model.4SqVenue', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

config: {
    fields: [
        {name: 'name', id: 'id'}
    ]
}
});
```

My store:

```
Ext.define('App.store.4SqVenues', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
requires: [
    'App.model.4SqVenue'
],

config: {
    model: 'App.model.4SqVenue',
    storeId: '4SqVenuesStore',

    proxy: {
        type: 'jsonp',
        url: 'foursquare venue request',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: 'response.venues'
        }
    }
}
});
```

My view:

```
Ext.define('App.view.4SqVenues', {
extend: 'Ext.List',
xtype: '4SqVenuesCard',
requires: [
    'App.store.4SqVenues'
],

config: {
    fullscreen: true,
    itemTpl: '{name}',
    store: '4SqVenuesStore'
}
});
```

The response from the 4sq API:

```
{
"meta": {
    "code": 200
},
"response": {
    "venues": [
        {
            "id": "4a3ad368f964a52052a01fe3",
            "name": "Four Peaks Brewing Company",
            "contact": {
                "phone": "4803039967",
                "formattedPhone": "(480) 303-9967",
                "twitter": "4PeaksBrewery"
            },
            "location": {
                "address": "1340 E 8th St",
                "crossStreet": "at Dorsey Ln.",
                "lat": 33.4195052281187,
                "lng": -111.91593825817108,
                "distance": 1827,
                "postalCode": "85281",
                "city": "Tempe",
                "state": "AZ",
                "country": "United States"
            },
            "categories": [
                {
                    "id": "4bf58dd8d48988d1d7941735",
                    "name": "Brewery",
                    "pluralName": "Breweries",
                    "shortName": "Brewery",
                    "icon": {
                        "prefix": "https://foursquare.com/img/categories/nightlife/brewery_",
                        "sizes": [
                            32,
                            44,
                            64,
                            88,
                            256
                        ],
                        "name": ".png"
                    },
                    "primary": true
                }
            ],
            "verified": true,
            "stats": {
                "checkinsCount": 24513,
                "usersCount": 8534,
                "tipCount": 235
            },
            "url": "http://www.fourpeaks.com",
            "likes": {
                "count": 0,
                "groups": []
            },
            "menu": {
                "type": "foodAndBeverage",
                "url": "https://foursquare.com/v/four-peaks-brewing-company/4a3ad368f964a52052a01fe3/menu",
                "mobileUrl": "https://foursquare.com/v/4a3ad368f964a52052a01fe3/device_menu"
            },
            "specials": {
                "count": 0,
                "items": []
            },
            "hereNow": {
                "count": 1,
                "groups": [
                    {
                        "type": "others",
                        "name": "Other people here",
                        "count": 1,
                        "items": []
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
}
```

Comment: Show me how do you doing making request?

Comment: The request string I pass through the proxy url is as follows (not including the access credentials) and recieves a similar json response as the one I included above:
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?near=tempe,az&categoryId=4bf58dd8d48988d116941735&client_id=ID&client_secret=SECRET&v=20120519

Answer (score 2):

I have a very similar issue. Basically all is good if I load the json without the rootProperty defined. But once I define it things stop working (bad configuration error reported in Architect).

So the belwo works opnlu until I define the rootProperty as 'records'

```
{ "records" : [ { "artist" : "Champion",
        "index" : 1,
        "recordid" : "r00899659",
        "trackname" : "1 To 2"
      },
      { "artist" : "Champion",
        "index" : 2,
        "recordid" : "r00899668",
        "trackname" : "Is Anybody There?"
      }
      .......
    ],
  "rowcount" : 10,
  "timestamp" : "1/07/2012 5:05:19 AM"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first, you have to wrap it in a function call as Per documentation for the response. Then you may have to use a convert function inside your model. Such as setting the root property to response, and then using convert to bring in all the other data from the venue property.